# Java 8 stream directory listing not sorting as expected

Tags: java, sorting, stream

Started working with Java8 and using streams, but I can't see why the first piece of code does not sort the directory listing by file date, and yet the second does?
The first maps before sorting and the second sorts before mapping.

```
   System.out.println("This does not work as far as sorting by date "
            + "- it sorts by alpha");
   Files.list(Paths.get("C:\\ProgramData\\Dummy"))
            .map(Path::getFileName)
            .sorted(
                    (s1, s2)
                    -> s1.toFile().lastModified()
                    >= s2.toFile().lastModified() ? 1 : -1
            )
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("--------------------");

    System.out.println("This sorts by date");
    Files.list(Paths.get("C:\\ProgramData\\Dummy"))
            .sorted(
                    (s1, s2)
                    -> s1.toFile().lastModified()
                    >= s2.toFile().lastModified() ? 1 : -1
            )
            .map(Path::getFileName)
            .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("--------------------");
```

Comment: Both snippets of code *do* sort by modified date.

Comment: Side note: you could simplify your comparator with [`Comparator.comparingLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-), for example `sorted(comparingLong(s -> s.toFile().lastModified()))`

Comment: On the Side Note - Thanks @andersschuller, I wasn't aware of that one, and you can even have 
`.sorted((Comparator.comparingLong((Path s) -> s.toFile().lastModified())).reversed())` for descending order

Comment: I've tested and both these fragments sort by modified date.  Accordingly I've flagged to close as typo/unreproducible.